# Access to database and importing data to Magento

Tags: database, magento, model, import

I am considering building some sort of mechanism, that would import data to Magento database. 
However, as I read in documentation, it was recommended to use models available in Magento by default if possible.

My question would be, whether it is possible to use model approach, without creating Magento module and then execute this code from command line?

Or the best idea would be to use module, but what if I would intend to build two import mechanisms, where one uses custom table (perhaps I may need one more table for one customization, but this table would stand apart) and another uses tables and models available in Magento?

Comment: Actually i would recommend for you to stick with serverside tools for this. Keep in mind that PHP file upload has a size limit (default is 2MB), which makes this whole process somewhat futile. As for accessing "models" directly - it will be quite hard, because Magento is very tightly coupled. You basically need to include whole framework just to make that *hack* work. Also, I'm removing *mvc* tag ... topic not related to it in any shape or form.

Comment: just bootstrap magento and you will be able to use outside of the framework.  look in the index file for how magento does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bootstrap Magento and use it from command line create a `php` file starting with:

```
<?php
  require_once '../Mage.php'; //correct path to Mage.php
  $app = Mage::app();
  Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
```

Comment: Hi WojtekT, do you have example how to call particular model created by myself to insert some data to db when you implement everything outside magento as above? I tried Mage::getModel('Namespace_Packagename_Model_Modelname'); and failed